# How to dynamic select options each webforms seperately?

Tags: 7

Currently I have a table of records webform (The node identifier of a webform) and a list of users, Associated with the webform table nid
The group has kept a list of users webform's (The node identifier of a webform).

The purpose is to be in accordance with a different view webform to fill a single page, you can automatically bring out the webfrom belong to fill a single page to view a list of users group, the following screen embedded in it, and you want to automate the dynamic select options each webforms seperately, That each webform node page has a list of  dynamic select options users group.

If the user fills again webform view to fill a single page, select a person of a certain list of users, and finally to be able to produce the data stored. To record the value webfrom submit sid and webform nid and selected personnel.

How do I make it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't entirely understand your question, but I believe that you want to customize a webform based on the user currently logged in.

To do this you can use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7).

All webform have an ID that starts webform_client_form_ so you check check for this, and then make any modification as necessary.

E.g:

```
function MY_MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

    //drupal_set_message("Form ID is : " . $form_id);

    if(substr($form_id, 0, 20)=='webform_client_form_') {

        global $user;

        // make changes to form here

    }
}
```